A single verb for "repair/correct", "finish", "improve", "redone"
I'm a foreigner. Is there a verb to cover all of the following meanings:

to repair or correct something
to complete something (e.g. to finish writing a book)
to improve something
to recast something as an improvement (e.g. to get rid of an awkward sentence by replacing it with a completely different one)

One of the options I consider is "to fix". But it seems to me it works well for the 1st meaning only, more-or-less for the 2nd meaning, and I'm not sure at all it works for 3 and 4.
Despite of some comments, in reality this question is not about software or computers. I'm simply curious.

What leads you to suspect that there might be one word with so many meanings (or with so broad a meaning)?

Americans use 'fix' more than we British do, but I don't think it's possible for (2). It could work for (3) and (4). (NB It's redo - redone is the past participle.)

I’m voting to close this question because choosing names for software constructs is specifically outside of our site's scope per our [help].

There is a word in British English, but (a) it is dialect (northern English) (b) it is virtually unknown in American English.
(I heard it regularly when I lived in Yorkshire, but have not heard it at all since I have been living near London.)
OED
fettle (v.) 1.a. transitive. "To make ready, put in order, arrange. Now only dialect to put to rights, ‘tidy up’, scour; also, to groom (a horse), attend to (cattle).**
Collins Concise English Dictionary © Harper Collins Publishers::

fettle /ˈfɛtəl/ vb (transitive)
(1. to line or repair (the walls of a furnace) (technical))

Brit dialect to prepare or arrange (a thing, oneself, etc), esp to put a finishing touch to

to repair or mend (something)



See this post at Word Reference forums: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fettle.54094/#post-389266

to repair or correct something - I've just fettled thy watch. It's
telling the right time now.
to complete something (e.g. to finish writing a book) "There! That's it! The book's fettled."
to improve something - That house of yours needs fettling if you want it to look good."
to recast something as an improvement (e.g. to get rid of an awkward
sentence by replacing it with a completely different one) - "That
sentence there... If you replaced "Joyous" with "happy", it'd fettle
the problem."


How could this OP use a word like this? The word is super interesting but also completely out of place for the question's apparent context...

And also used  in stonemasonry for cleaning up the edges of paving stones using hammer and chisel.   I heard it a few years ago in a Youtube video where some stonemasons from the north of England were laying a sandstone patio.

Lambie is right, but the aim of ELU is not primarily to answer questions exactly as they are formulated, but to use them to bring out facets of grammar, semantics etc (and this includes dialect usages) that are of interest and may possibly be of use to others. This answer certainly meets those requirements.  But I can't bring myself to upvote, close fit though this word is. It is so rarefied.

@Lambie You ask "How could this OP use a word like this?" The answer is "I have no idea and I don't care. He may be writing a book about a family in Lancashire - He may be discussing English dialects, He may be writing to a Yorkshireman - He may be translating a poem by a Sheffield poet.  The OP gives his reason for asking as pure curiosity. This goes to that curiosity. What is your actual objection? (PS I am grateful to Edwin Ashworth for his comments.)

+1, though one might fay it’f unfettling how clofe the word if to “settle”. :P

He says: I'm a foreigner. So...I object to a general question being answered with a term that is very off the beaten path.

@Lambie I sincerely believe that even foreigners are allowed to have a general curiosity.

Set has something close to these meanings, as well as dozens of other meanings. Quotes from Merriam-Webster.

to repair or correct something: "to restore to normal position or connection when dislocated or fractured: set a broken bone"

to complete something: it can mean to make many things e.g. jelly, cheese, etc, create a table setting. Fix something as "set bail", "to fix in a desired position (as by heating or stretching)". "To arrange (type) for printing" would relate to finishing a book. Or "to defeat (an opponent or a contract) in bridge".

to improve something: to sharpen as in "set a razor", again various senses meaning to fix in the correct position as with a bone or "to arrange (hair) in a desired style by using implements (such as curlers, rollers, or clips) and gels or lotions", "to put and fix in a direction".

to recast something as an improvement: not sure what the difference is between this and the previous, but many of the cases from 2 and 3 will apply. And lots more e.g. "to adjust (a device and especially a measuring device) to a desired position: set the alarm for 7:00, set a thermostat at 68; also : to adjust (something, such as a clock) in conformity with a standard"



This seems to be the "Procrustean approach" of forcing the innocent word into a meaning that fits.

Some of these usages are, as Greybeard I think implies, from the deep places of the largest dictionaries. To set an incorrect maths answer? / To set a set of cigarette cards? / To set prison conditions? / To set a sentence? I think the question is too broadly scoped ... but this one is borderline.
